# How do I add OR?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just want to do something different if it is Thursday.  I'd love to also make a list of holidays, and have those do something different too, but the Thursday if my first question.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(E3,2)<6, "Wake up", "Sleep")
```

Comment: Where do you want to add OR ? show an Example

Comment: If weekday is Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday, return "Wake up". If weekday is Thursday, return, "Remote".  If Saturday or Sunday, return, "Sleep".

Comment: Perhaps give [nested `IF`s](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-%E2%80%93-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8) a read. Your statement included 3 `If`s, which is a clue to how to write this as a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `OR(c1,c2,...)` function which evaluates to True when any one of its argument conditions is true. For example,

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(E3,2)=1,WEEKDAY(E3,2)=2,...), "Wake up", IF(OR(...), "Sleep", "Remote"))
```

Comment: Like this?  =IF(OR(WEEKDAY(E3,2)=1,WEEKDAY(E3,2)=2,3,4), "Wake up", IF(OR(WEEKDAY(E3,2)=7), "Sleep", "Remote"))

Comment: Actually, no. `3` and `4` by themselves are not logical conditions. You have to write `WEEKDAY(E3,2) = 3` and `WEEKDAY(E3,2) = 4`.

Comment: I get this now. I didn't realize until trying this now that Sunday was 0. I thought it was 1. That sure helps me understand what's happening, LOL.

Comment: =IF(OR(WEEKDAY(E3,2)=1,WEEKDAY(E3,2)=2,WEEKDAY(E3,2)=3,WEEKDAY(E3,2)=5), "Wake up", IF(OR(WEEKDAY(E3,2)=4), "Remote", "Sleep"))

Comment: And the last one is just an else, correct?  This is working. I will try adding the holidays later, now that I see how this works.

Comment: Yes! To add the holidays, you would put, in the current last else, an `IF` that checks for the holidays, and its else would be what is currently in the last else, that is "Remote".

Answer (score 1):

OR is nor necessary and without seems to me a  little neater:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Holiday,E3),"Other",IF(WEEKDAY(E3)=5,"Remote",IF(WEEKDAY(E3,2)>5,"Sleep","Wake up")))
```

`Holiday` is a named range for the dates of *something different*.

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` function takes a list of parameters, i.e. `OR(param1, param2, param...)`.

The formula below will do one thing ("Wake Up") on every day except Thursday.

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(E3,2) < 4, WEEKDAY(E3,2) > 4), "Wake Up", "Sleep")
```

Using your date format (2) where Thursday is day 4, it says if the day of the week is less than 4 OR greater than 4, say "Wake Up", otherwise say "Sleep".

**Update**

To accommodate the updated original question, the function below will:

- If the date is a holiday specified in the `Holiday` named range --> Holiday
- If the week day is Thursday --> Remote
- If the week day is Saturday or Sunday --> Sleep
- Else (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday) -> Wake Up

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Holidays,A2)>0,"Holiday",IF(WEEKDAY(A2,2)=4,"Remote",IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2, 2)=6,WEEKDAY(A2, 2)=7),"Sleep","Wake Up")))
```

Note that I've also specified Friday 7/5 as a holiday.

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Now Wed is the only one that's wrong. It says Sleep, when it should say "Wake up". Sunday and Saturday say "Sleep". Thursday says, "Remote". Mon, Tues, Fri say, "Wake up".

Comment: =IF(OR(WEEKDAY(E3,2)<3,WEEKDAY(E3,2)=5),"Wake up",IF(WEEKDAY(E3,2)=4,"Remote","Sleep"))

Comment: Thank you too, Scott! I will try adding this in later too.

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(E3,2)<3,WEEKDAY(E3,2)=5),"Remote",IF(WEEKDAY(E3,2)=4,"Sleep","Wake up"))
```

- Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday - Remote
- Thursday - Sleep
- Sat, Sun - Wake up

Comment: Sorry, I want to return "Remote","Sleep", or "Wake up".  Thanks!

Comment: Just change them accordingly in the Formula. :)

Comment: I don't see how to return three arguments.  My Excel skills are super rusty.

Comment: @SusanAnspaugh .. Changed the Answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I know you've asked about using `OR`, and have already accepted an answer, but I wanted to point out that you can also use `VLOOKUP` to make your logic clearer and more readable.

First, you can create a table of weekdays and lookup values, like this:

```
+---+-----+-----------+---------+
|   |  A  |     B     |    C    |
+---+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1 | nbr | weekday   | alarm   |
| 2 | 1   | Sunday    | Sleep   |
| 3 | 2   | Monday    | Wake Up |
| 4 | 3   | Tuesday   | Wake Up |
| 5 | 4   | Wednesday | Wake Up |
| 6 | 5   | Thursday  | Remote  |
| 7 | 6   | Friday    | Wake Up |
| 8 | 7   | Saturday  | Sleep   |
+---+-----+-----------+---------+
```

Then, assuming the date you're checking is in `E3`, you can use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(E3,1),$A$2:$C$8,3,FALSE)
```

The formula becomes even clearer when converting your lookup data to a table and using a named range:

[image: table]

[image: named_range]

```
=VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(date_entered,1),tWeekdays,3,FALSE)
```